# Change Image when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, dom-events

I have an image and a button within a panel.

When the button is clicked I would like my image to be replaced with another image at random based on an array of stored images.

I'm stuck on implementing a change image function within the button.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using jQuery by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        var imageList = ['one.png', 'two.png', 'three.png', 'four.png'];

        $('#btn').click(function(){
            var imgName = imageList[Math.floor(Math.random()*imageList.length)];
            $('#image').attr('src', imgName);
        });

    });


</script>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<img id="image" src="someimage.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refToYourImage.onclick = function() {
    refToYourImage.src = arrOfRandomImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrOfRandomImages.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<img id = "IM" src = "someImageReference"/>
<button onclick = "changeImage(document.getElementById('IM'))">Change image</button>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeImage(image) {
    var images = new Array{"image paths","here"};
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * images.length);
    image.src = images[rand];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to have a separate panel with a card layout for the images. This way you can easily add animations when swiching the images.

Example

```
   new Ext.Panel({
 id:'imagePanel',
     layout: 'card',
     cardSwitchAnimation: 'fade',
items:[
    {html:'<img src="/img1.jpg" />'},
    {html:'<img src="/img2.jpg" />'},
    {html:'<img src="/img3.jpg" />'},
    {html:'<img src="/img4.jpg" />'}
]
    });
```

And then have this to switch the image

```
Ext.getCmp('imagePanel').setActiveItem(Math.floor(Math.random()*numImages);
```